# Partial passing variable error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials

I have a rails 4 app that has some code like:

```
<% @store.products.each_with_index do |p, i| %>
   <%= render "product_fields", locals: {product:p, index: i} %>
<% end %>
```

and the product_fields partial looks like:

```
//LOTS OF HTML CODE HERE
<% if params[:action] == "edit" %>
   <%= render "edit_product_fields", locals: {p: product, i: index } %>
<% end %>
```

But'm getting the error (on _product_fields.html.erb):

```
NameError in Products#edit
undefined local variable or method `p' for #<#<Class:0x00000101e35da8>:0x00000101a86568>
```

What's going wrong? Also, I was wondering if there is a cleaner way of passing variables to partials within partials? I tried to do something like `locals: {w:w}` (so there would be consistent naming for the variables, but it didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Can you post the full error and your full `product_fields` partial?

Comment: @JKen13579, Sure just posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails 3+ you don't need to provide a locals option. Just pass the variables directly.

```
<%= render 'product_fields', product: p, index: i %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `partial` keyword in your render, otherwise, the locals would not work.

```
<%= render partial: "product_fields", locals: { product: p, index: i } %>

<%= render partial: "edit_product_fields", locals: { p: product, i: index } %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it doesn't change the error?